# iOS ADAL & Swift 3.0, does it support programmatically passing in of UserID and password

Tags: ios, swift3, adal

We would like to have our users land on our own login page with our look and feel and pass that login id and password silently over to ADAL login page.  Is that possible?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, the resource owner password grant (username/password) is not supported in ADAL Objective-C.

While it's enticing to use this to customize your sign in page, there are serious implications that may impact your end users. For example, your app would no longer be able to sign in users that require MFA.  Moreover, there are security implications in capturing user's creds.  There's an [excellent blog post](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/) on the right time to use this flow.

If you're concerned with app branding on the sign in page, you can customize a significant chunk of it. Check out the [custom branding in Azure AD doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/customize-branding) if you want the exact steps for how to do this.

Comment: From the documentation, what I understand is we can create custom branding for each client.  Is there a way to create a custom brand for an application?  Our design team would like the login page to have our own look and feel and logo if possible?